# Build confirmation form for shopping cart in Symfony2

Tags: php, validation, symfony, entities

I have `Cart` service, which holds `ProductOrder`'s passed to it. It is later saved into session. It looks like that:

```
class Cart
{
    /**
     * @var ProductOrder array
     */
    private $orders = array();
    /**
     * @param ProductOrder $order
     */
    public function addOrder(ProductOrder $order)
    {
        $this->orders[] = $order;
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductOrder $order
     */
    public function removeOrder(ProductOrder $order)
    {
        $this->orders = array_filter($this->orders, function($item) use($order) {
            return $item->getProduct()->getId() != $order->getProduct()->getId();
        });
    }

    /**
     * @return ProductOrder array
     */
    public function getOrders()
    {
        return $this->orders;
    }
}
```

This is not entity! But I want to validate in the end ( with `Callback` constraint ) whether there is enough `Product` for every `ProductOrder` in database. This is my confirmation form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('orders', 'collection', array(
            'label' => false,
            'type' => new ProductOrderType(),
        ))
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Service\Cart'
    ));
}
```

`ProductOrderType` has only quantity field. And this is view for this form:

```
  <form method="post">
        {% for order in form.orders %}
            {{ order.vars.data.product.name }} {{ form_widget(order) }}<br />
        {% endfor %}
        {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
        <input type="submit" value="{{ 'entity.productOrder.buy'|trans }}">
    </form>
```

I want to render all `ProductOrder`'s with it's quantity, and haven't found better way to do it, BUT I don't think this is proper way to do it. Also: I don't know how to add `Callback` constraint to this form - because in my opinion separate `validation.yml` file is reserved for entities only.

Please note that I don't want to use a third-party bundle.

Comment: yeah, that's helpful. thanks.

Comment: well, my bad. Too often I ended up with answers like "there is a bundle for it", which was very annoying and that's why I wanted to make it clear, that I want to write it by myself.